# How to obtain the msg format of a topic on runtime?

Tags: python, rostopic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to implement a dynamic subscription mechanism, that monitors the available topics. Firstly it takes a view to the msg format of new topics and subscribes to this one depending on a special data format. The first step, to know the current available topics works fine with the following code:

```
available_topics_old=[]
def monitor():
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      master = rosgraph.masterapi.Master('/rostopic')
      available_topics = master.getPublishedTopics('/') 
      new_topics=[]
      for topic in available_topics:
         if not topic in available_topics_old:
            new_topics.append(topic)
      if new_topics:
          # here I need to know the format(file) of the assigned msg
   rospy.sleep(1.0)
```

How can I get the msg format of the topic?

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9836/how-to-obtain-the-msg-format-of-a-topic-on-runtime?/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are unofficial/volatile APIs, but you can look at how they introspect on the graph to pull the data out (most of this can be done with the masterapi or filesystem operations):

```
import roslib.message
import rostopic
import rosmsg

type_name = rostopic.get_topic_type('/rosout', blocking=False)[0]
if type_name:
    message_class = roslib.message.get_message_class(type_name)
    message_text = rosmsg.get_msg_text(type_name)
    full_message_text = message_class._full_text
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5